# Fade between transparency and a color in Graphics

Tags: java, graphics, transparency, fade, alpha

I am trying to accomplish something like shown below (fade between white and transparency) without adding a picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a BufferedImage, the alpha channel is simply the most significant byte of the result of `getRGB()`:

```
int alpha = (image.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
```

So, you can change the alpha whilst preserving the color using:

```
int original = image.getRGB(x, y);
int newColor = (original & 0x00FFFFFF) | (alpha << 24);
image.setRGB(x, y, newColor);
```

(assuming `0 <= alpha <= 255`).